# Mansfied Toilet Compatibale bowls?

Tags: plumbing

Are there compatible bowls for a Mansfield tank, I have a Mansfield Model 148 tank and no bowl?

Comment: VTC - This question is seeking product recommendations regarding specific brands -- basically a shopping question. This type is not a good fit for this site because it will outdate quickly and not likely be of use to the general user here even if an answer were to come forward.

Comment: In short, as Jimmy's answer goes into more detail, a new toilet is almost always going to be cheaper and much easier to find - and all of its parts will work together properly (or you can complain to the seller until they do...) Put it out in the yard as a porcelain planter, that's pretty much what they are good for once separated.

Answer (score 1):

I will answer by using this question as a platform to address the difficulty and expense, at least in the U.S.A., of procuring one replacement piece (tank or bowl) for a 2-piece toilet.

There are numerous manufacturers of toilets from many countries and locales, most offering (at least) several designs and several colors of each design.

The primary reason is financial. Supply and demand dictates that sales of complete toilets would dwarf sales of just a tank or bowl. With essentially zero demand there would simply be no financial incentive to ship, wholesale, then retail the individual components for separate sale. If they did, **the cost would likely be very near the cost of buying a complete toilet**, which would undoubtedly rankle most consumers.

That being said, there are exceptions. A good plumbing shop may very well have just a tank or bowl available for the basic top seller at their shop and in the most common color (white). You also may be able to order a replacement from the manufacturer, through a distributer. What you are *not* likely to find is replacements for anything no longer manufactured (designs change frequently, for many reasons); anything in a color that is not white; anything not originally sold in large quantities; anything from a distant land.